# Accessing to all partition in dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I'm using dask but i'm struggling with it.
i tried this syntax just to get access for the first partition.

```
df = df.partitions[1].compute()
```

but now i want to know how to get access for all the partition.

I tried this :

```
df = df.partitions.compute()
```

But i get this error

```
'IndexCallable' object has no attribute 'compute'
```

How can i do to get all the partitions ?

thank you for your help.

ps: sorry for my frenchenglish

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `.compute` will bring the full dataset into memory...

Comment: I'm trying with my script  to compare 5 millions rows from my dataframe to a public database.

Comment: Hmm, and the public database is in another dataframe? Are you comparing them row-by-row?

Comment: The public database is a json file that i turn it into a dataframe. Yes exactly i compare them row-by-row. This is why i want to get all the "dask dataframe" to do it . But i don't know how to do it. Right now I'm just able to do it with one partition...  I'm a neophyte with dask and python also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the dataframe into memory you can use:

```
df.compute()
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's unclear what you are trying to do exactly, but from the comments it sounds like you are trying to do a join. You don't need to load the entire dataframe (i.e. by calling `df.compute()`) into local memory to do that.

If the size of the public database you mention is relatively small and fits into a single Dask Dataframe partition, you can use [the `.merge()` method](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.merge.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.merge).

```py
small = small.repartition(npartitions=1)
result = big.merge(small)
```

Otherwise refer to [the Dask docs here](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-joins.html#joins) for other use cases and a general discussion on joins in distributed environments.